# Excel VBA: Problem with assigning dynamic variables to range function

Tags: excel, vba, function

I started of by assigning variables using the Dim function. These variables are dynamic and change every time the code is executed. The variables are "opendate" and "enddate". When i wanted to assign them in a range function so to get the max and min values within that range, it fails every time. I know how to get min and max values if the range is specified directly i.e range("D20:D41") but i want the correction when it comes to a case such as this. Please see attached code below as i know im not fully coherent with this explanation. Thanks

```
Public sub aom()

'This is a normal case scenario

set rng=activesheet.range("D20:D40")

Range("L32").Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(Rng)
Range("L33").Value = WorksheetFunction.Min(Rng)

End sub
```

```
Public Sub aomhigh()

'This is my case

'Firstly i declare my variables(note that those variables are numbers up to 4 dp)

Dim opendate As Double
    activecell.offset(0, -7).Select
    opendate = activecell.Value

activecell.offset(0, 7).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
activecell.offset(-1, 0).Select

Dim enddate As Double
    activecell.offset(0, -7).Select
    enddate = activecell.Value

'Then i think the way to declare them in the range function is something like this even though it seems i never get it right

Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range(" + opendate + : + enddate + ") '<- This is where the problem is

'Then the normal finding for max and min values as usual

Range("L32").Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(Rng)
Range("L33").Value = WorksheetFunction.Min(Rng)

End sub
```

Comment: `" + opendate + : + enddate + "` should be `opendate & ":" & enddate`

Comment: Do you want to construct a range from two numbers?

Comment: In fact you can't construct a range from two numbers to 4dps!

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SO.

You can build dynamic ranges, though you would need to change your aproach to it.

If you want to use the Range object in the way you are using it at the moment, then you would need something similar along the lines:

```
Dim opendate as String, enddate as String 'Not as Double!
opendate = "D20"
enddate = "D40"

Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range(opendate & ":" & enddate)
```

If you have a fixed column with this values, but only want to change the rows dynamically, you could change that into something like this:

```
Dim opendate As Long
    activecell.offset(0, -7).Select
    opendate = activecell.Value

activecell.offset(0, 7).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
activecell.offset(-1, 0).Select

Dim enddate As Long
    activecell.offset(0, -7).Select
    enddate = activecell.Value

Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("D" & opendate & ":D" & enddate)
```

It really all depends on the content of those cells you are getting those values from, and a range doesn't take any decimals as far as I`m aware, though I've never tried. If the values are with up to 4DPs, but your code still depends on them, i suggest using a formula to get the rounded value to the nearest full number, i.e.: 4.5744 = 4 or 5 (depending on your needs).

That being said, I advise against using `.Select` and `activecell.` as your "dynamic" selections, it kind of defeats the purpose of making your code dynamic...

Comment: Hi there and thank you for your answer! However i seem to encounter a problem by implementing it this way as instead of the actual numbers i get zero "0" as min and max values ;/

Comment: Do you have a few samples of actual values you have there? assuming your values are 0.xxxx ... you need to find a way to translate those values in actual usable row numbers (i.e. rounding as I've suggested).